# how is `while(1)` optimized not to take all resources?

Tags: c, linux, loops, scheduling

Suppose I have some code that does this:

```
while(1) {
      scanf("%c", &key);
      // if E or e, exit
      if (key == 'E' ||  key == 'e')
          break;
}
```

This obviously does not take up all the resources of even a single core. It just... "sits" there until someone actually presses an E. My question is: how does the runtime find out that it should not take up all the resources of a core just waiting for a scanf? Is scanf a special case in that it is I/O and as such the OS schedules it out until a key is effectively pressed? Can I somehow force it to be `while`ing all the time by say, adding a `a++` inside the loop?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use up all CPU time, intentionally?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: No. I'm trying to find out why it doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps someone will press CTRL+Z on Windows, or CTRL+d on Linux, and you'll notice that this question is invalid because when that happens, the CPU-hogging nature of this infinite loop will dawn upon you. I say it way too often: *Remember to check the return value!* This goes for *every* function. Your loop should look more like: `while (scanf("%c", &key) == 1) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: I've no idea what you're saying... sorry. :)

Comment: @DervinThunk, I'm saying: **Always** check the return value of `scanf`, or your code might malfunction in subtle or devastating ways.

Comment: @DervinThunk The point of the above is that when the input stream is closed, then `scanf` will return immediately (returning `EOF`) and then the loop _will_ take up all CPU resources the OS gives the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is scanf a special case in that it is I/O and as such the OS schedules
>   it out until a key is effectively pressed

That's exactly what is happening. In this case `scanf` is a **blocking** operation. That is, if it can't be executed immediately (nothing in the input buffer) the OS simply puts your process to sleep, remembering to wake it up when something turns up.

> Can I somehow force it to be whileing all the time by say, adding a
>   a++ inside the loop

An `a++` won't change anything. You won't be able to peg the CPU as long as you have long-waiting blocking calls.

---

> until a key is effectively pressed

In Linux input is usually "cooked". That is, pressing a single key isn't typically enough (you also need to hit return before your process gets a chance to look at the data).

---

As Basile correctly mentions in the comments `scanf` itself may not always block. If there's enough input in the stdio buffer `scanf` will just return it. If not it will then call `read(2)` which *can* block.

Comment: are there "blocking" ops that are not IO?

Comment: @DervinThunk Interesting question. Look for `pause(2)`. In practice all the system call needs to do (in Linux) is call `wait_event_interruptible` or similar. So it's not strictly for I/O.

Comment: Alright. I'll look it up. Thanks, I'm trying to accept your answer but it seems they've recently changed it and now it's timed. I will accept as soon as possible.

Comment: @DervinThunk Wait! Don't accept it just yet. Wait some more, perhaps better stuff turns up.

Comment: @DervinThunk, some examples of blocking non-IO sysalls are: [nanosleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) (ok, that one is pretty obvious) and [vfork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork).

Comment: Actually (at least on Linux), `scanf` will call a blocking operation (the `read(2)` syscall). `scanf` is not always blocking (if the `stdin` file buffer has bytes, it could use them) but it may call a blocking primitive (`read(2)` on Posix systems). On Windows, you have equivalent things.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's right. If there's sufficient input in the stdio buffer `scanf` won't block.